# Async Syntax Error

Tags: python, discord.py

Hi I am trying to make a discord bot while hosting it on my raspberry pi via ssh and i tried running this code: 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rapptz/discord.py/async/examples/reply.py

but I get this error: 
[image: Error] Can  anyone help please? Thanks -Jake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the correct Python version.  [discord.py](/questions/tagged/discord.py) is supported only for Python 3.4+, and the `async` syntax is only supported in Python 3.5+.

You're probably calling a system-managed Python2 installation, try `python3 TagBot.py` (you probably don't need to `sudo`)

Comment: I used ' python3 TagBot.py' and I get the same error how can I download the latest version of python on my pi?

Comment: Please use `python3 --version` to figure out what version you have. As for installing python3.5+, please do a simple google search to learn how to do it on your OS distribution.